# Mic not working on MBP 12,1 (mid 2015) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, macbook, microphone

I recently erased mac os on my macbook pro 12,1 (mid 2015 retina) in favor of  ubuntu 18.04 . My main remaining issue is the audio system. There is no input registering from the internal mic (only white noise). In addition, no headset microphone is detected when plugged in.

I think it worked briefly when the ubuntu installation was fresh, but it was never reliable (becoming silent when switching to hdmi output and never coming back ) and  after fiddling around with alsa and pulse audio, I can never bring it back. 
I have now in my alsa-base.conf:

options snd-hda-intel model=auto

Though I had tried this as well without success:
options snd-hda-intel model=mbp101

Any ideas?

Regards,
Nik